# Control a subprocess (specifically gdb) in multiple ways

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am developing a wrapper around gdb using python. Basically, I just want to be able to detect a few setup annoyances up-front and be able to run a single command to invoke gdb, rather than a huge string I have to remember each time.

That said, there are two cases that I am using. The first, which works fine, is invoking gdb by creating a new process and attaching to it. Here's the code that I have for this one:

```
def spawnNewProcessInGDB():
    global gObjDir, gGDBProcess;
    from subprocess import Popen
    from os.path import join
    import subprocess
    binLoc = join(gObjDir, 'dist');
    binLoc = join(binLoc, 'bin');
    binLoc = join(binLoc, 'mycommand')

    profileDir = join(gObjDir, '..')
    profileDir = join(profileDir, 'trash-profile')

    try:
        gGDBProcess = Popen(['gdb', '--args', binLoc, '-profile', profileDir], cwd=gObjDir)
        gGDBProcess.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Send a termination signal to the GDB process, if it's running
        promptAndTerminate(gGDBProcess)
```

Now, if the user presses `CTRL-C` while this is running, it breaks (i.e. it forwards the CTRL-C to GDB). This is the behavior I want.

The second case is a bit more complicated. It might be the case that I already had this program running on my system and it crashed, but was caught. In this case, I want to be able to connect to it using gdb to get a stack trace (or perhaps I was already running it, and I simply now want to connect to the process that's already in memory).

As a convenience feature, I've created a mirror function, which will connect to a running process using gdb:

```
def connectToProcess(procNum):
    global gObjDir, gGDBProcess
    from subprocess import Popen
    import subprocess
    import signal

    print("Connecting to mycommand process number " + str(procNum) + "...")

    try:
        gGDBProcess = Popen(['gdb', '-p', procNum], cwd=gObjDir)
        gGDBProcess.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            promptAndTerminate(gGDBProcess)
```

Again, this seems to work as expected. It starts gdb, I can set breakpoints, run the program, etc. The only catch is that it doesn't forward `CTRL-C` to gdb if I press it while the program is running. Instead, it jumps immediately to `promptAndTerminate()`.

I'm wondering if anyone can see why this is happening - the two calls to `subprocess.Popen()` seem identical to me, albeit that one is running gdb in a different mode.

I have also tried replacing the call to `subprocess.Popen()` with the following:

```
gGDBProcess = Popen(['gdb', '-p', procNum], cwd=gObjDir, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but this leads to undesirable results as well, because it doesn't actually communicate anything to the child gdb process (e.g. if I type in `c` to start the program running again after it is broken upon connection from gdb, it doesn't do anything). Again, it terminates the running python process when I type `CTRL-C`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "Instead, it jumps immediately to promptAndTerminate()" Isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: Well, actually, no. In the first example, it doesn't jump to `promptAndTerminate()`. Instead, it passes the `CTRL-C` event to gdb first, causing gdb to break the process being debugged. I've verified that `promptAndTerminate()` is not being called in the first version of the function - it's actually giving me an interactive `(gdb)` prompt, and breaking the running process. In the second version, it immediately calls the `promptAndTerminate()` function. I'd ideally like the first version, but I'm confused as to why they are exhibiting different behavior.

Comment: I suggest avoiding all these problems by using `exec`. Or do you need to return to the Python script?

Comment: Hm... I hadn't considered that. I guess I don't really need to return to the python script. I'm not familiar with `exec`, though... does it spawn a process and then terminate? How exactly is communication handled then? Does the process take over input from the parent?

Comment: You complete replace the Python process with the `exec`d process.

Comment: Let me try it and see what I come up with.

Comment: @Niklas B: This worked quite well. If you post it as an answer, I will accept. Thank you!